# Returning and Echoing multiple variables

Tags: php

I've written the following PHP script which is intended to echo all three variables that are captured in the constructor `Book` within the class `Book`.

I'd like PHP to echo all the three variables. However, at the moment it only echoes one of the three.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

  class Book {

           protected $title;
           protected $author;
           protected $yearPublished;   

          function Book($title, $author, $yearPublished)
          {
           $this->title=$title;
           $this->author=$author;
           $this->yearPublished=$yearPublished;
          }

         function Summary()
         {
           return $this->title;
           return $this->author;
           return $this->yearPublished;
           sprintf($this->title, $this->author, $this->yearPublished);
          }
  }


$test= new Book("Pride and Prejudice","John Doe","2016");
$test->Summary();
echo $test->Summary();
```

Comment: You are returning from the method. Which means eveything after it won't be executed. This has nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need both `$test->Summary();
echo $test->Summary();` - You can safely get rid of the first one and just do `echo $test->Summary();`, it's valid syntax.

Comment: Cheers for that input @Fred -ii-!

Comment: @user3608262 You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this function to

```
function Summary(){
      return $this->title;
      return $this->author;
      return $this->yearPublished;
      sprintf($this->title, $this->author, $this->yearPublished);
}
```

To

```
function Summary(){
      return sprintf('%s %s %s',$this->title, $this->author, $this->yearPublished);
}
```

Comment: There's no point in leaving commented out code in place if it's non-functional

Comment: @stwalkerster It is to let him know what is not required in the code. he can later remove it.

Comment: You're a legend @Amit Ray!

Answer (score 3):

1. **the `Summary()` method exits after the first [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)**

   > If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.

   You probably wanted this:

   ```
   function Summary()
   {
       return sprintf('%s %s %s', $this->title, $this->author, $this->yearPublished);
   }
   ```

   Also your call to [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#refsect1-function.sprintf-parameters) was missing the first argument (`$format`).
2. **don't use "old-style" (pre-PHP 5) constructors as they are deprecated, use [__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) instead**

   > Old style constructors are DEPRECATED in PHP 7.0, and will be removed in a future version. You should always use __construct() in new code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation @ShiraNai7! You're a legend mate!

Answer (score -1):

You need to use magic method `__toString` if you want to print object as string
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

```
class Book
{
...
    public function __toString()
    {
        return sprintf(
            '%s %s %s',
            $this->title,
            $this->author,
            $this->yearPublished
        );
    }
...
}

$test = new Book("Pride and Prejudice","John Doe","2016");
echo $test;
```

Comment: OP isn't trying to cast his object to a string.